# Best security and performance testing tool as a fresher tester

Tags: manual-testing, load-testing, security-testing

What are the best security and performance tool as a fresher tester i should know? I am new to the testing field and my seniors have asked me to learn tools for performance and security testing.

Comment: Could you please edit this question to give more information? What kind of applications are you trying to test? What do you want in a tool? (Easy to learn, good online resources, cost...). Without more information, this question will likely be closed for being either opinion-based or too broad.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "silver bullet" tool which would be the best, it totally depends on your application technologies, infrastructure, your experience in terms of programming languages, etc.

The list of tools is quite easy to to figure out:

- [Security Testing Tools](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Appendix_A:_Testing_Tools)
- [Performance Testing Tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/performance/)

However you might want to narrow them down according to your requirements, i.e. take a look at [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide for example investigation